Include a font asset in the html sent to Expo Print (React Native)
I'm needing to print a barcode in a Expo (React Native) App. I've tried to  require the tff file (see below), but this does not work for me. If I use the same methodology to include an image, however, it works fine.


try {
    const fontAsset = Asset.fromModule(require('@/assets/fonts/LibreBarcode39-Regular.ttf'));
    const fontBase64 = await manipulateAsync(fontAsset.localUri ?? fontAsset.uri, [], {base64: true});
}catch(e){
    console.log("Error loading font: " + e)
}




Actually, I was over-complicating this, it turns out.
So, to get the font, you just:
const fontAsset = Asset.fromModule(require('@/assets/fonts/LibreBarcode39-Regular.ttf'));

And then in the style tag, do:
@font-face {
     font-family: 'LibreBarcode39-Regular';
     src: local('LibreBarcode39-Regular'), url(${fontAsset.uri}) format('truetype');
}

And then usage like this:
font-family: 'LibreBarcode39-Regular';

Hopefully, if someone else runs into this issue, this will be of help.
